# Prove a graph Containing $2k$ odd vertices doesn't contain $k-1$ distinct paths.

Tags: graph-theory

It's proven [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/103536/prove-a-graph-containing-2k-odd-vertices-contains-k-distinct-trails) that a connected graph with $2k (k>0)$ vertices of odd degree has $k$ distinct paths (paths are distinct when they don't share edges). But can we get $k-1$ distinct paths? I'm really not sure. The trick involving Eulerean circuit certainly doesn't do it's magic here, and I'm at a loss as to how to approach this any other way.

Comment: Each odd vertex must be the end of at least one path. A path has two end points. Therefore, there must be at least $k$ paths.

Answer (score 2):

This question was answered by a comment:

> Each odd vertex must be the end of at least one path. A path has two end points. Therefore, there must be at least $k$ paths. – hbm Jan 8 '14 at 17:09